# How do I find out which accounts have not been imported when using the Import Wizard?

Tags: data-import-wizard

Using the Import Wizard I performed an import using the Account Name and a custom field which contained 171 records in total. When I ran the import I got an email stating 56 had failed but the csv attached to the email is empty so I can see which records this has failed against. 
Is this a known issue or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are the System Administrator you will be able to see the Bulk Data Uploads page which contains a link which allows you to download a results file for the data upload. This contains the record id for the successful uploads and the errors for the failed records. Unfortunately it does not include the full text of the records unlike the Data Loader error files however you should be able to find the values in the source file that have caused the errors.